# How to add printing of number of days in a year also for leap years?

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar, leap-year

I am having trouble adding it so that my program prints out the days in a certain year. What's messing me up is the leap years. Don't want to scrap it.

I am confused and was trying to put it together by myself and should have asked for help. wanted to know if there was a way to fix it or if i had to scrap it and start all over again. My problem so far is designating the days. since i'm not sure if i should just separate the days by the month over just have the total for each year and do that for the leap year as well.

```java
if (month == 1) {
    month1 = "January"; 
    daysInMonth = 31;
} else if (month == 2 ) {
    month1 = "February";
    daysInMonth = 28;
} else if (month == 3) {
    month1 = "March";
    daysInMonth = 31;
} else if (month == 4) {
    month1 = "April";
    daysInMonth = 30;
} else if (month == 5) {
    month1 = "May";
    daysInMonth = 31;
} else if (month == 6) {
    month1 = "June";
    daysInMonth = 30;
} else if (month == 7) {
    month1 = "July";
    daysInMonth = 31;
} else if (month == 8) {
    month1 = "August";
    daysInMonth = 30;
} else if (month == 9 ) {
    month1 = "September";
    daysInMonth = 30;
} else if (month == 10) {
    month1 = "October";
    daysInMonth = 31;
} else if (month == 11) {
    month1 = "November";
    daysInMonth = 30;
} else if (month == 12) {
    month1 = "December";
    daysInMonth = 31;
} else if (month >= 13 ) {
    System.out.println("this date does not exist please try again");
}

if (month <= 12) {
    System.out.println("this is the year you put in " + year);
    System.out.println("this is the month you entered " + month1);
    System.out.println("this is how many days are in that year " + daysInMonth);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the goal here? Just use Java's [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class. Create a calendar by calling `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()`, set the month with `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1)` (keep in mind the value is 0-based, so 1 would be February not January), get the month name with `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(cal.getTime())`, and get the days in the month with `cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`.

Comment: Alternatively if you want to continue doing it on your own, please, for the sake of everyone involved, use a [HashMap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) instead of having an if statement for every single month.

Comment: wasn't trying to use the calendar class was trying to figure another way out. was trying to see if there was a way for me to save this or if I have to start over from scratch and try other ways. p.s still thank you

Comment: If I were you I would start over. There are much better ways to do this. Like I mentioned previously, use a [HashMap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp). It's much cleaner and much easier to manage.

Comment: thank you and how do I label this question as solved. Nvm found it

Comment: If you find yourself writing the same block of code multiple times in a row, there is almost always a better way to do it.

Comment: @Jesse please do not suggest the super old and obsolete `Calendar` class. There's the `java.time` package, which was introduced with Java 8 (!) and should be the preferred choice in every way.

Comment: What @QBrute says (in fact frankly a bit shocked that someone recommends `Calendar` in 2022). For production code use java.time; classes `YearMonth` and/or `LocalDate`. If doing the calculation by hand is an exercise, it’s a good one, go on. `HashMap` is an option, other options include an array, a `switch` expression and obviously the `if`-`else` chain you already have.

Comment: Are you wanting the number of days in the *month*, in the *year*  or both? It’s like your code contradicts your body text.

Comment: Understanding *Nvm* as never mind, you may delete the question. You have got a delete link under it.

Comment: @OleV.V.  The only examples I could find of getting the month name were all done using Calendar. I see examples of it being used literally everywhere. I wasn't aware there was a better way to do it.

Comment: @Jesse Yes, unfortunately a plethora of web pages still showing the use of the old and poorly designed classes of which `Calendar` is just one are floating around on the Internet from the old days. Ignore them and instead go to pages like [the official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: For printing the month name use either [the `Month` enum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) or [a `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). @Jesse

Comment: @Jesse [Online demonstration](https://rextester.com/BWBP87114)

Comment: You should use an array instead of... that

Comment: @ user16217248 yeah I figured out a better way than was curious to see if I could salvage something out of that but I decide to start over and got a better result.

Answer (score 1):

You would get several advantages if you used `java.time` for this:

- it will be easier to check for invalid input
- you can easily find out if a year is a leap year or not
- you can easily print month names and even abbreviations depending on a locale, that means you can switch languages and standards

Here's a small example for a method:

```java
public static void printInformationAbout(int month, int year) {
    // create an instance of month and year from the arguments
    Year y = Year.of(year);
    Month m = Month.of(month);
    
    // collect information about the year
    boolean isLeap = y.isLeap();
    int days = y.length();
    // and print that information
    if (isLeap) {
        System.out.println(year + " is a leap year and has " + days + " days");
    } else {
        System.out.println(year + " is a regular year and has " + days + " days");
    }
    
    // print month info (directly this time)
    System.out.println(String.format("%s (month no. %d) has %d days in %d",
                            m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH),
                            m.getValue(),   //  number of the month
                            m.length(isLeap), // length of month in days
                            year));
}
```

If you used this in a `main`, let's say like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printInformationAbout(5, 2020);
}
```

You'd get the following output:

```
2020 is a leap year and has 366 days
May (month no. 5) has 31 days in 2020
```